# JQuery Closure dynamic controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I'm having some confusion with closures

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            var cname = '#closingTimePicker' + i;
            $(cname).datetimepicker({
                format: 'LT'
            });

            var oname = '#openingTimePicker' + i;
            $(oname).datetimepicker({
                format: 'LT'
            });

            $(oname).on("dp.change", function (e) {
                $(cname).data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
            });
            $(cname).on("dp.change", function (e) {
                $(oname).data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
               //Loop issue here
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

>

In the above script i'm confused how to apply closure so that i cloud get the correct date picker based on the loop. any suggestions and importantly explanation would be a great help.

Thanks,

Comment: For the code you've posted just use $(this) instead of $(oname) at the point you've identified as having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

every loop cname and oname gets a new value. so when dp.change on a oname object is triggered, cname has always the last value it gets in the loop.

try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initPicker(cname, oname)
{
    // paste here the rest of the loop
}

for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var cname = '#closingTimePicker' + i;
    var oname = '#openingTimePicker' + i;
    initPicker(cname, oname);
}
</script>
```

[EDIT]
short explanation:
scopes live as long as their variables. so "scope" initPicker is 7 times initialized with different filled variables.
[/EDIT]

enjoy (-: